# ONVIF reports Error for GetProfiles: The action requested requires authorization and the sender is not authorized

Tags: xml, soap, onvif

I am trying to experiment with ONVIF features using a HIKVISION camera. It works fine with request for **GetServices**. Here is the request:

```
       <s:Envelope
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <s:Header>
            <Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
                xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <UsernameToken>
                    <Username>admin</Username>
                    <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#Passwo    rdDigest">ttToXMBbkvcTwrNmFXi98IkJjI+ZcnCgTDvqd52CKtE=</Password>
                    <Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">uN08HgV/71BD39TvmdM0cw==</Nonce>
                    <Created
                        xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">1970-01-01T00:46:39.000Z
                    </Created>
                </UsernameToken>
            </Security>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <GetServices
                xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">
                <IncludeCapability>true</IncludeCapability>
            </GetServices>
        </s:Body>
       </s:Envelope>
```

When I tried for **GetProfiles**, it fails, even though the same logic is used with the same type of authentication. The error returned in the response is:

**Action requested requires authorization but the sender is not authorized.**

Here is that request:

```
       <s:Envelope
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
        xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <s:Header>
            <Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
                xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <UsernameToken>
                    <Username>admin</Username>
                    <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#Passwo   rdDigest">CRzaA1hDfuG031Lztc7ZsYEtiGo1O/7wFSlaCf3rBwk=</Password>
                    <Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">jwP2WzyxdbXkMX8fD8QDrQ==</Nonce>
                    <Created
                        xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">1970-01-01T00:46:39.021Z
                    </Created>
                </UsernameToken>
            </Security>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <GetProfiles
                xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl">
                <Type>All</Type>
            </GetProfiles>
        </s:Body>
       </s:Envelope>
```

The same functions are used to generate the SHA256 hash for both requests.

Comment: hey! @sunny have you been able to resolve the issue? I'm facing the same problem and ws wondering if you could point me to the right direction.

Comment: @IgorLitvinovich  Unfortunately not. I was busy with some other work and have returned to it now. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Not yet, for now we're investigating if firmware update or some configuration updates can make the difference. I was able to identify that it works for some hikvision cameras and also works for Dahua cameras. So for now I tend to blame the firmware or the wrong configuration. I'll keep you posted if I find something.